# C# Access Query

Tags: c#, ms-access

[image]

How can I set value from text box in this query.The Value must be a Path
When it's like this one single quotes It's Ok

```
string strcmd = "UPDATE svo_Settings SET svo_Settings.[Value] = 'Something'  WHERE(((svo_Settings.Name)= 'OS'))";
```

But When I want to change 'Something'  to textbox text I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't leave out the quotes:

```
string strcmd = "UPDATE svo_Settings SET svo_Settings.[Value] = '" + OsValue + "' WHERE svo_Settings.Name = 'OS'"
```